# How to extend easement to new piece of property being severed?

Tags: real-estate, property, easement

I'm in Ontario, Canada. I'm looking at purchasing a piece of land behind my parents cottage. I'll be severing 1-2 acres from a much larger parcel, and because it is behind my parents property there is no official access.

My parents would be perfectly fine with extending the easement/right of way through the corner of their property to get to my parcel, although is this allowed? Or would I need consent from every single person along the existing easement to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

**You are in luck!**

In Ontario, *existing easements transfer to a severed portion.*

[Bulletin 2005-2](https://www.ontario.ca/land-registration/2005-02-easements-and-release-easements), *Easements and Releases of Easements*, from the *Title and Services Office* of Ontario answers your question directly in 1.0.3 Division of Dominant Lands:

> *Upon the severance of a parcel of land, all existing easements appurtenant to the whole, benefit each severed portion.*

*Note 1:* If you are not familiar with the terminology of easement law, the first few paragraphs give a nice summary.

*Note 2:* My [quick search](https://www.ontario.ca/search/land-registration?sort=desc&query=easements&field_bulletins_year_value=all) suggests this is the most recent bulletin on easements.